# Looking for possible words to describe certain meanings

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

In order to come up with a good company name in the field of Information Technology, I'm working on compiling two groups of words.

**First:**

Words that have similar meaning to: improvement, doing things right, success, building well, etc... Something like "Bettering" but bettering itself does not sound good to me.

Examples:

- Improvement
- Bettering
- Boosting

**Second:**

Words that mean: a place where working, thinking, tinkering takes place

- Workshop
- Workroom
- Labs

English is not my first language so I was hoping you could help me. Could you help me with suggestions? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming, and also is also subjective; have a look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I say name if *[German surname] + Laboratories*

Answer (score 1):

The first word doesn't have to be a real English word, but should definitely have recognizable roots that portray advancement, improvement, and doing things right and well. Think of prefixes and suffixes. A lot of companies, IT and other, tend to use the following:

1. Intel- (from intelligent) *Intel, Intellius*
2. Exe- (from executive) *Exelon*
3. Rad- (from "radical") There's a remote access application called *Radmin*.
4. Prof- (from "proficient") A made-up word you could use is *Profiant*.
5. Avant- suggestive/indicative of moving forward. *Avantra*
6. Nov- suggesting/indicative of something new. *Novartis, Noven*
7. Ver- suggesting/indicative of truth, reliability. *Verizon, Verisign*
8. -ant - suffix that can mean supporting, promoting, representing, or doing. *Alliant, Allegiant, Reliant, Profiant* (as suggested above).
9. -tek/-tech - suggesting that it's a technologically-based company. *Meditech, Aerotek* (though they're a job placement service.)
10. -a - not sure if it's an actual suffix, but you see it a lot. *Splenda, Concerta, Avantra, Humana* (sounds reassuring but may not be "aggressive" enough for what you need.)

Search for Latin and Greek roots, and find the ones that apply and appeal to you. Also look at lists of company names, even if they're not IT. Drug names and companies help, at least in suggesting word roots.

Sometimes, you may omit the second word, though I personally like Labs. Use that if you decide to include the second word.

Answer (score 0):

I think some words that might work for your purpose are:
For Improvement: refine, refined, or refining, development, enhance or advanced, enrich, perfect as a verb with the accent on the second syllable, revitalize, or upgrade.
For workshop you might consider: think tank, fabricators, producer, production group, or foundation, or fundamentals, foundry (suggests metal making).

These words can be used in several forms and could be combined with another word that states exactly what your product will be, such as the refined programming, programming refinery, IT foundry, enhanced IT factory, IT advancement factory...

Play around with some combinations of the words and check their definitions to see how they might fit together.